# Assigning values within Arrays

Tags: java, arrays

The following code prints "YYYY", but for the life of me, I can't understand why. The last line prints both values stored in first, but  I don't see where first's values change.

```
String[] first = {"x", "y"};
String[] second = first;
second[0]=first[1];
second[1]=first[0];
System.out.println(first[0]+first[1]+second[0]+second[1]);
```

Comment: First and second reference the same array. Anything you do to one you do to the "other".

Answer (score 1):

You create array `{x,y}` and the pointer to that array is stored in the variable called `first`

```
String[] first = {"x", "y"};
```

Then you copy the value of variable `first`, which is that POINTER into the variable `second`. Both variables are pointing to the same structure, which is our `{x,y}` in this case.

```
String[] second = first;
```

You say that what is stored in second cell in array you are poinint to is copied to the first cell. Which copy `y` to first cell and at this moment, you have `{y,y}`

```
second[0]=first[1];
```

Analogic to previous, however it does not change anything (you already have `{y,y}`)

```
second[1]=first[0];
```

And the result is obvious I hope :)

```
System.out.println(first[0]+first[1]+second[0]+second[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable `first` references an array.

```
first  -> [ 0:x , 1:y ]
```

The variable `second` references the same array as referenced by the variable `second`.

```
second -> [ 0:x , 1:y ] <- first
```

The element at index 0 of the array referenced by `second` now references the element at index 1 of the same array referenced by `first`.

```
second[0] -> first[1] // second -> [ 0:y , 1:y ] <- first
```

The element at index 1 of the array referenced by `second` now references the element at index 0 of the same array referenced by `first`.

```
second[1] -> first[0] // second -> [ 0:y , 1:y ] <- first
```

Answer (score 0):

Java arrays are assigned by reference so

```
String[] second = first;
```

essentially means both second and first are now referring to the same array
i.e the values inside the array are NOT copied.